# SQL Server (ORM) select data from database - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, orm, entity-framework-core

I tried to get data from database using SQL Server and Entity Framework Core (ORM), but I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

First I created a class to represent simple table of database:

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<info> info { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        _ = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["users"].ConnectionString);
    }
}

public class info
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote the connection string in my `web.config` as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="users" 
         connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-0VD537B\SQLEXPRESS;Database=users;trusted_connection=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the `ValuesController` the `POST` method works without problems:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{
        using (var db = new Database())
        {
            var user = new info { Name = "Name1", ID = 1 };
            db.info.Add(user);
            _ = db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

but when I try to display data from my `GET` method, I got that error

```
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
        List<string> users_arr = new List<string>();

        using (var db = new Database())
        {
            var users = db.info;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                users_arr.Add(user.ToString());
            }
        }

        return users_arr;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFltk.png)

Comment: There is more to the exception detail, you could "copy details" and add it to your question as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I solve the problem my mistake was in info class, I declared ID as int but it is varchar in database so that's why i got invalid cast.

Answer (score 0):

1- Changing the type of ID to be compatible with the type in database

```
public class info
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

2- Edit value of ID in post method.

```
// POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        using (var db = new Database())
        {
            var user = new info { Name = "Name1", ID = "1" };
            db.info.Add(user);
            _ = db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Get method looks better like this

```
// GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        List<string> users_arr = new List<string>();

        using (var db = new Database())
        {
            var users = db.info;
            
            try
            {
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    users_arr.Add("Name:"+user.Name+"   ID:"+user.ID);
                }
                return users_arr;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new string[] {"error:", e.Message };
            }
        }
    }
```